# Bigcommerce Status Update - Starting Out Help Needed

Tags: json, curl, bigcommerce

I'm trying to update an order's status in BigCommerce by running a batch file from the command prompt using curl. I'm very new to this as you might can tell. The error I'm receiving is "The JSON content provided as input is invalid. Please check your JSON syntax before trying again." I've managed to execute some GET commands with no problem. Here is the code I'm running. I followed the example on Big Commerce's site. I'm sure this is something simple. Please feel free to talk to me like I'm four years old. I appreciate your help.

curl --request PUT  -u "myuser:mypassword"  -H  "Content-Type: application/json"  --data-binary '{"status_id":1}'  https://mystore.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/orders/100

Answer (score 0):

You can try with '{"status_id":"1"}'